# Gatling sbt assembly- jar file cannot created?

Tags: sbt, gatling, sbt-assembly

I am using gatling tool for performance testing.My gatling code is running perfectly. i am using intellij IDEA for my project. I am trying to create a jar file. It cannot created. i think this is sbt problem.please someone correct my sb My build.sbt file is here:

```scala
import io.gatling.sbt.GatlingPlugin
import sbtassembly.MergeStrategy

parallelExecution in Test := false

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin, AssemblyPlugin)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
 .configs(IntegrationTest)
 .settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*)
 
Project.inConfig(IntegrationTest)(baseAssemblySettings)

mainClass in assembly := Some("gatling.GatlingMain")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.6.2" % IntegrationTest,
  "org.scalacheck" % "scalacheck_2.11" % "1.13.5"  % IntegrationTest,
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1" % IntegrationTest,
  "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "2.2.5" % IntegrationTest,
  "io.gatling" %  "gatling-test-framework" % "2.2.5" % IntegrationTest,
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.0" % IntegrationTest
)

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value /"resources"

assemblyJarName in (IntegrationTest, assembly) := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"
```

when i am trying to create a jar file using sbt command sbt "it:assembly"
It shows the following error

```
  [error] 1 error was encountered during merge
  java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
  /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec-http/jars/netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
 /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
 /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
 /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/jars/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:140)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:25)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:67)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:57)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:83)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:245)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:242)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  [error] (it:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
  [error] /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  [error] /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  [error] /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec-http/jars/netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  [error] /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  [error] /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
  [error] /Users/james/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
```

My sbt version is 0.13.16 and my scala version is 2.11.8. please someone help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't need io.netty.versions.properties from all the io.netty libraries, one may be enough. I think something like this should work:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case p if p.endsWith("io.netty.versions.properties") =>
   MergeStrategy.first
 case x =>
   val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
   oldStrategy(x)
}
```