# How to create a jar file for Gatling gRPC Load test with only test class

Tags: scala, sbt, load-testing, gatling, scalapb

I am using the code from https://github.com/alexromanov/gatling-grpc-tests-sample
i have added new protobuf under src/main and added a newSimulation.scala under src/test/scala/load. The code works fine and able to run. Now the problem i want a jar that can execute the newSimulation.scala

so my 2 questions?

1. is there a way we can create a jar using which i can run the load test script
2. If not how can i write a main class which may invoke the tests from there

Thanks

i tried `sbt assembly` and `sbt test:assembly` dont think that it worked, as it kept asking me for a main class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify

```
assembly / mainClass := Some("com.example.Main")
```

?

See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

I can't see that in their `build.sbt` https://github.com/alexromanov/gatling-grpc-tests-sample/blob/main/build.sbt

(Just in case, what are your versions of `sbt` and `sbt-assembly`?)

[Multiple main classes with SBT assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283666/multiple-main-classes-with-sbt-assembly)

[How to set main class in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467423/how-to-set-main-class-in-build)

[How to pass mainClass argument using sbt assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925533/how-to-pass-mainclass-argument-using-sbt-assembly)

[sbt-assembly - can not find main class in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980428/sbt-assembly-can-not-find-main-class-in-jar)

[why sbt-assembly failed to auto detect main class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726507/why-sbt-assembly-failed-to-auto-detect-main-class)

Comment: Hey, i tried mentioning the main class on the build.sbt, but did not work
sbt version : 1.4.3
sbt-assembly version : 0.15.0

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way we can create a jar using which i can run the load test script

If you want to create a executable jar, [this is not supported usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830435/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-io-gatling-app-gatling#comment112873608_63830435).

> Gatling has a set of official launchers: zip bundle, maven, sbt, gradle and FrontLine.

However, if you want to, it's doable. There's already another question asking for the exact same thing.
[Gatling sbt assembly- jar file cannot created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650365/gatling-sbt-assembly-jar-file-cannot-created)

---

If you upgrade your Gatling SBT plugin, you can simply run `sbt Gatling/enterprisePackage`. That task creates a fat jar in the `target/gatling` directory.

Move that jar to `lib/` in the Gatling bundle.
You can start the simulation by calling `./bin/gatling.sh -s load.GrpcSimulation`.

Since the sample repo is pretty old, you will have to also upgrade quite a lot of things (e.g. sbt, other sbt plugin(s), libraries versions) to upgrade the Gatling SBT plugin.

Comment: i placed the jar inside lib/ and on running i am getting this error


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.gatling.core.cli.CommandLineConstant.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at io.gatling.recorder.cli.CommandLineConstants$.<init>(CommandLineConstants.scala:23)
 at io.gatling.recorder.cli.CommandLineConstants$.<clinit>(CommandLineConstants.scala)
 at io.gatling.bundle.GatlingCLI$$anon$1.<init>(GatlingCLI.scala:61)
 at io.gatling.bundle.GatlingCLI$.main(GatlingCLI.scala:54)
 at io.gatling.bundle.GatlingCLI.main(GatlingCLI.scala)

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch.

Comment: thanks George, yes gatling bundle was of different version. fixed it but now running into new issue ----  io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry getDefaultRegistry
WARNING: No NameResolverProviders found via ServiceLoader, including for DNS. This is probably due to a broken build. Any idea on this? tried this [https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2149] but didnt help

Comment: I think that should be a different question. Include your `sbt` settings in the new question. Also try unzipping the `.jar` and see if there is `io/grpc/internal/DnsNameResolverProvider.class`.